# Using the jQuery Plugin with Teechart - dateFormat

Tags: jquery, teechart

I am trying to create a date/time chart using the jQuery plugin for TeeChart. I cannot get the dateFormat to set correctly.
Without jQuery, just creating a TeeChart on a canvas I can use

```
Chart1.axes.bottom.labels.dateFormat = "dd/mm/yy";
```

and this displays correctly.
Using a simple jQuery plugin example I would expect to translate this into

```
    $("#canvas").teechart({
        chart: {
            axes: {
                bottom:{
                    labels: {
                        dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy',
                    }
                },
            },
    })
```

But this displays the labels as something like Tues March 28 2016
I have chased the code through `jquery.teechart.js` and it appears to be setting the option in the correct place but nothing I set there affects the label.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had left out the link for
    src="./../../TeeChart/src/date.format.js"
Hence no worky. Surprised that Teechart did not raise some exception.
Thanks for your helps